# creating dynamic tweet button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter

So I am trying to create new tweet button each time the user click on `newQuoteBtn` and the value of `quoteHere` is changed. In the tweet button I trying to change the `data-text` to the value of `quoteHere` but all I get is the word "Document" I am using [this](http://jsfiddle.net/chris27/DQw5b/4/) method. What am I doing wrong?

```
<script>
    function newQoute() {
      var randomQ = Math.floor(Math.random() * quoteArr.length);
      document.getElementById('qouteHere').innerHTML = quoteArr[randomQ];
    }
</script>

  <div class="qoutediv container-fluid">
    <p id="qouteHere">
      qoute
    </p>
  </div>

<button id="newQuoteBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="newQoute()">New Qoute</button>


<div id="tweetBtn">
      <a class="twitter-share-button" href="http://twitter.com/share" data-url="http://test.com" data-text="REPLACEME">Tweet</a>
      <script>
        ! function(d, s, id) {
          var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
          if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
            js = d.createElement(s);
            js.id = id;
            js.src = "//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
          }
        }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs");
      </script>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    $('#newQuoteBtn').on('click', function(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
      // Remove existing iframe
      $('#tweetBtn iframe').remove();
      // Generate new markup
      var tweetBtn = $('<a></a>')
        .addClass('twitter-share-button')
        .attr('href', 'http://twitter.com/share')
        .attr('data-url', 'http://test.com')
        .attr('data-text', $('#qouteHere').val());
      $('#tweetBtn').append(tweetBtn);
      twttr.widgets.load();
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: `P`aragraphs don't have `val`ues; they do have `text`.

Comment: damm you are slick. Thank you it worked!!!!